# What happens when you copy a database table?

Tags: sql

This is kind of a high-level question. I am trying to join two tables and generate a report based on the results, but I only interested in some of the data in the able I am joining to.

I wasn't sure which was a better approach:

1. Write a complicated statement with lots of WHERE conditions to filter out the data I don't want included.

or

2. Copy the initial table and drop records I don't want included in my report before joining to the other table.

Is there an approach that is generally favored? Do copied tables maintain the relationships that the original table had to others in the database?

Comment: The first approach is better (and typically faster)

Comment: If you are frequently using a complicated query you can create a view containing the complicated query. You can then query the view using only the conditions which change from one time to the next, for example the dates.

Comment: Don't copy tables to query data, it's what I see juniors doing so often and doesn't make a lot of sense of you think about it. SQL databases are smart and designed to be able to query databases quickly (look up how indexes work). Copying data is almost always slower since you'd be writing a copy of the data somewhere, most likely the disk, but even duplicating a whole table in memory can be costly since that memory is usually being used to cache some other data that you are now throwing away just to make room for your copy. Don't do this, learn how to index and query correctly.